# How to change/control the output precision in gcc or g++?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I have the following piece of code written in c++ and compiled by g++ 4.8.

```
double x = 0.123456789;
cout << x << endl;
```

I don't understand why I only get the output

```
0.1234567
```

even I  define x as `long double x`. It probably a quite naive question, but can any one give me some hits?

Comment: Have you even tried googling "C++ output precision" or something similar? If so, tell us what you've found and what you don't understand about it.

Comment: If you've searched for it, the compiler name probably threw the search engine off the track (my results when including "g++" are useless). A less specific version of your title, "How to change/control the output precision in c++?", returns good search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `precision` function or the `setprecision` manipulator to set the number of significant figures (or decimal places, if you also use `fixed`).

```
cout.precision(10);  // 10 significant figures
```

or

```
cout << setprecision(10); // also 10 significant figures
```

or

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(10);  // always fixed-point format, 10 decimal places
```

By default, the precision is 6.

Answer (score 3):

[This page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) has all you need, namely that you should use the `std::setprecision` stream manipulator.

```
double x = 0.123456789;
std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << x << std::endl;
```